# Excel combining variables from multiple columns

Tags: excel

I have four separate columns of data (numerical data such as "1, 2, 3" and numerical/alphabetical data such as "3A, 3B").  Each column has about 100,000 rows.

I am trying to select certain rows from each column and combine them.  For instance, in column AJ I would like to select "1, 2", from column AG I would like to select "3A, 3B", and so forth.  I then want the selected rows to all appear in one larger column.

Can anybody direct me on how to accomplish?

Here is a screen shot of some columns:

[image: picture of data]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your data and another of your desired results?

Comment: A mock up of the data would help us visualize better what you want.

Comment: I added a screen shot

Comment: Okay, now what would you expect the output to be?

Comment: So, I need to make a column that extracts the 1s and 2s from AG and the 3As and 3Bs from AJ and places them into one separate column (while still retaining their other rows)

Comment: So, With the data in these 18 rows, what exactly would be the output? Not an explanation but the actual output.

Comment: So the output would contain rows 5, 9, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 15, 19  all in one contained column.

Comment: I will work on a formula that gives you that, but the next question is the row number the end or are you going to use that in another formula? Because we might be able to skip the middle step and go straight the the answer.

Comment: I wanted to figure out what the formula would look like and was planning on adding other columns / rows of information.  In total I have about five or six columns to combine.

Answer (score 0):

If cell A1 was "1, 2" and B1 was "3A, 3B" then in C1 you could use the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)
```

This would create "1, 23a, 3b
" in C1. To fix the gaps change it to:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,", ",B1)
```

Which gives cell C1 as: "1, 2, 3a, 3b". You could then obviously add more values, use ranges or use dynamic values or column names depending on what your table structure is.

Comment: My problem is that each column has other values.  So column AJ has individual cells containing 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.  I want to pick just 1 or 2 from column AJ.  Column AG contains 1A, 1B, 3A, 3B.  I want to pick just 3A and 3B from column AG.  Then I want to combine those into a new column (so combine the 1s and 2s from column AJ with the 3As and 3Bs from column AG into a new column).

Answer (score 0):

This array formula will give you the rows that are true in one or the other columns:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((($AG$2:$AG$19=1)+($AG$2:$AG$19=2)+($AJ$2:$AJ$19="3A"))>0,ROW($2:$19)),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

It is an array formula and will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving edit mode.

To add criteria just add another to the if statement part.  For example if I wanted to test for `3B` I would add `+($AJ$2:$AJ$19="3B")` after `...+($AJ$2:$AJ$19="3A")`

Also to enlarge the references, make sure you enlarge all.  So all the `19`s would increase to the last row of data.

[image]

Now if you want to get a value in another column that corresponds with these rows then add `INDEX`.  For example if you want the value in Column A then:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$19,SMALL(IF((($AG$2:$AG$19=1)+($AG$2:$AG$19=2)+($AJ$2:$AJ$19="3A"))>0,ROW($2:$19)),ROW(1:1))-1),"")
```

This will use the value returned to grab the corresponding value.

The `-1` at the end is because we are starting on the second row and we need a 1 based number to use the INDEX.

**EDIT**

As per you comments I fixed your formula.  There were some weird characters that excel did not like.  I had to retype the whole formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((($AG$2:$AG$29663=1)+($AG$2:$AG$29663=2)+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663="3B")+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663="3A")+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663=3)+($AK$2:$AK$29663=1)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=1)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=2)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=3)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=4)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=5)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=1)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=2)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=3)+($AK$2:$AK$29663=2))>0,ROW($2:$29663)),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

**EDIT2**

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(((($AG$2:$AG$29663=1)+($AG$2:$AG$29663=2)+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663="3B")+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663="3A")+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663=3)+($AK$2:$AK$29663=1)+($AK$2:$AK$29663=2))*(($CK$2:$CK$29663=1)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=2)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=3)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=4)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=5)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=1)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=2)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=3)))>0,ROW($2:$29663)),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Comment: So I added to the command and mine looks like the following.  Where do I copy / paste it to compute the actual data?                    =IFERROR(SMALL(IF((($AG$2:$AG$29663=1)+($AG$2:$AG$29663=2)+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663=”3B”)+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663="3A")+($AJ$2:$AJ$29663=3)+($AK$2:$AK$29663=1)+($AK$2:$AK$29663=2)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=1)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=2)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=3)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=4)+($CK$2:$CK$29663=5)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=1)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=2)+($DN$2:$DN$29663=3))>0,ROW($2:$29663)),ROW(1:1)),"")

Comment: In an empty column put in a cell, hit ctrl-shift-enter, then copy down far enough that you are getting blanks.

Comment: So I paste the formula in an empty cell and pressed ctrl+shift+enter.  Nothing appears in that cell.  I then drag the right lower corner down and still nothing resulted.  Is my formula not correct?

Comment: @KangaRew see **EDIT**.

Comment: so now I am copying / pasting it and excel is automatically making a merge cell.  When I hit ctrl+shift+enter it gives an error message that merge cells are not allowed with arrays.

Comment: make sure you have only one cell selected.  paste it directly in the formula bar, not the cell.  Then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, not enter or tab.  Then copy down.  It working just fine for me.

Comment: I did what you mentioned and now it is resulting, but basically each cell just has a subsequent number from 0 to infinity.  So the first cell has 1 the next is 2, then 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: @KangaRew Well you have 15 criteria, any of which if true will result in the row appearing.  My guess is that you have at least one that is true in  that row.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the formula so that the at least one of the values in CK or DN must be present along with any of the other values?

Comment: @KangaRew see edit 2.  I usually do not do this.  You are changing the parameters of the question after getting an answer to the question asked.  That is frowned upon here.  There should be enough information to change the formula if you need to change more.